# Filter through Select2 AJAX results

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

Is it possible to search through returned results when using AJAX remote data? The example is as such:

1. Enter 5 digit zip code
2. Select2 searches (custom query) using zip and returns results in opt-group list with format of value = User ID, label = User Email
3. (desired) Filter through search results list by typing user email
4. (desired) Select result based off this method OR exit and start over

Has anyone done anything like this before? Is it natively possible or is it extensible in this way?

EDIT: Formatting

Comment: I'm with the same problem, did you solve it?